# ListView not displaying -- ListView Item Selection into webView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make a ListView that lists all League of Legends Champions.

**My current problem is that right now just the listview itself will not show on the screen** and cannot figure out why.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my champListAcivity:

```
public class champListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle fdsa) {
        super.onCreate(fdsa);

        ArrayAdapter<Champ> aa;
        ArrayList<Champ> champList = new ArrayList<Champ>();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChampListView);

            // I SKIPPED THE CODE CONTAINING THE ADDING OF THE CHAMPIONS
            // TO THE LIST BECAUSE ITS TOO LONG AND ALREADY RIGHT BECAUSE IT 
            // WORKED BEFORE AND I HAVENT CHANGED IT

        int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<Champ>(this, layoutID, champList);
        listView.setAdapter(aa);                        
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);

        Champ selChamp = (Champ) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String champURL = selChamp.getLink();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,webViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", champURL);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: when it worked ? show that cod as well

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, as the problem had nothing to do with the web view, and it just made it a bit harder for others to see the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting your content view in the `champListActivity`:

```
public class champListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle fdsa) {
        super.onCreate(fdsa);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_champ_list_name);  // <- missing!
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually figured it out a different way but just elimination the champListActivity class and just implementing it all in Main :/ Now the app just crashes when I click on an item. so there's something wrong with my webviewactivity.java. If you see anything wrong with that feel free to tell me. but I might just try to figure it out myself eventually.

Comment: You certainly may have **more** problems.  But, per the stack overflow Q+A format, we try to keep each question as specific as possible.  So, if there's still problems, post a **new** question, showing only the problem (WebView) code, and we'll take a look at it.